# How to maintain reference after replacing object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

**Context:**

I have a use case where i have to

- Find and update the original object using method.
- Replace the
  original object with a new object (Same structure).

The problem I am facing here is, at step2 when the object gets replaced the variables used in step1 doesn't get updated, it still has the old value.

i.e  At step 1 value becomes "hello" , at step 2 value becomes "replacedtext", though it updates the original object ,the variables filteredCanvas ,filteredcanvasobjects has old value "hello" instead of "replacedtext".

I am not sure where I am going wrong, Any suggestions would be helpful.

I have recreated the example below

**Code:**

```js
var originalObject = {
  canvases: [{
    canvasId: "canvasOne",
    canvasObjects: [{
      id: 1,
      type: "Rect",
      dummyText: "OriginalRect"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      type: "Text",
      dummyText: "OriginalText"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      type: "Image",
      dummyText: "OriginalImage"
    }]
  }]
}


var objectTobeReplacedWith = {
  canvases: [{
    canvasId: "canvasOne",
    canvasObjects: [{
      id: 1,
      type: "Rect",
      dummyText: "ReplacedRect"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      type: "Text",
      dummyText: "ReplacedText"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      type: "Image",
      dummyText: "ReplacedImage"
    }]
  }]
}


//------------- Original
var div1 = document.getElementById('originalObject');
div1.innerHTML = originalObject.canvases[0].canvasObjects[1].dummyText;
var div2 = document.getElementById('objectTobeReplacedWith');
div2.innerHTML = objectTobeReplacedWith.canvases[0].canvasObjects[1].dummyText;



//------------- Add hello
var addHelloToCanvasScope;

function addHelloToCanvas(canvas, canvasObject) {
  //replace text layer with hello
  canvasObject.dummyText = "Hello"
}

//Get new ad
var filteredCanvas = originalObject.canvases.find(ad => ad.canvasId === "canvasOne");
//Apply to layer
var filteredCanvasObject = filteredCanvas.canvasObjects.find(exlayer => exlayer.type === "Text");
addHelloToCanvas(filteredCanvas, filteredCanvasObject);


var div3 = document.getElementById('afteraddinghello');
div3.innerHTML = originalObject.canvases[0].canvasObjects[1].dummyText;;

//------------- Replace
originalObject = objectTobeReplacedWith;
var div4 = document.getElementById('afterreplace');
div4.innerHTML = originalObject.canvases[0].canvasObjects[1].dummyText;
var div5 = document.getElementById('filteredCanvas');
div5.innerHTML = filteredCanvas.canvasObjects[1].dummyText;
var div6 = document.getElementById('filteredCanvasObject');
div6.innerHTML = filteredCanvasObject.dummyText;
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #111;
  sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.problem {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>Original (Initial State)</h1>
originalObject:
<div id="originalObject"></div>
objectTobeReplacedWith:
<div id="objectTobeReplacedWith"></div>

<h1>After adding hello to originalObject (After using find and changing value within method)</h1>
originalObject:
<div id="afteraddinghello"></div>

<h1>After replacing originalObject with objectTobeReplacedWith</h1>
<br/> originalObject:
<div id="afterreplace"></div>
<br/> filteredCanvas:
<div class="problem" id="filteredCanvas"></div>
<br/> filteredCanvasObject:
<div class="problem" id="filteredCanvasObject"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here although you have replaced the original object, you did not update the value of `filteredCanvas`. That is why it is showing the previous value. After replacing the originObject you need to recalculate the `filteredCanvas`. You can do the following,

```
//------------- Replace
originalObject=objectTobeReplacedWith;
var filteredCanvas = originalObject.canvases.find(ad => ad.canvasId ==="canvasOne");
var filteredCanvasObject = filteredCanvas.canvasObjects.find(exlayer => exlayer.type === "Text");
addHelloToCanvas(filteredCanvas,filteredCanvasObject);
var div4 = document.getElementById('afterreplace');
div4.innerHTML = originalObject.canvases[0].canvasObjects[1].dummyText;
var div5 = document.getElementById('filteredCanvas');
div5.innerHTML = filteredCanvas.canvasObjects[1].dummyText;
var div6 = document.getElementById('filteredCanvasObject');
div6.innerHTML = filteredCanvasObject.dummyText;
```

Comment: Is there any other way to keep filteredCanvas always updated other than calling the method addHelloToCanvas again?

Comment: The way we are calculating filteredCanvas value from original object it is not possible to update filteredCanvas automatically when originalObject reference updates.